# Laravel Variable in Master Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an e-commerce system. I'm showing total items in cart. You can see it below.

[image]

When i'm creating cart view. I can pass variables using CartController like

```
return view('cart.index')
```

But in my template i have partials such as navbar.

view

```
  template
     partials
        navbar.blade.php
        footer.blade.php
        header.blade.php
     master.blade.php
```

If a user logs in they will see this $itemCount. Now i'm converting my project to a laravel project.

I should use $itemCount in every view. I'm asking about it. How can i do that ?

Comment: What do you mean with global variable?

Comment: We are passing variables with Controllers to blade template. For example CartController, ProductController etc. For every view i have to pass $itemCount variable. Because it is master template. I want to do it once for every place. $itemCount will be located in Navbar

Comment: Will you display multiple counters on each page or just related to the current Controller?

Comment: I think what you need is ViewComposers: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers. You can define, in which and what should be available in your views.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer in Laravel Manuel.

I mean **Sharing Data With All Views**

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->share('key', 'value');
}
```

We can share data with all view by using AppServiceProvider

Jeffrey Way's video is best about this topic.

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25

It is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 2):

> Once value is set into the session you can also retrieve from blade template.

In blade template add this things ( As per your requirements ).

$value = Session::get('key');

{{$value}}

[Please refer to Laravel Session](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#session-usage)